# Checkbox value is not getting for button submit

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a form with a text box and a checkbox. Checkbox is mutually exclusive. I want to pass the selected value when click submit button. Only the email value is getting and checkbox value is not getting. I'm totally new to Angular JS. Please help to fix this. This is what I tried

```
   <ng-form name="manageForm">

<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>E-mail</label>
  <input required md-asterisk name="email" ng-model="manage.model.email">

</md-input-container>

<div ng-repeat="designation in $manageController.designations">
  <md-checkbox ng-model="designation.checked" ng-change="$manageController.change(designation)">
    {{ designation.name }}
  </md-checkbox>
</div>

<div>
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary bm-button" ng-disabled="manageUsersForm.$invalid || manageUsersForm.$pristine" ng-click= "$manageController.submitUser(manage.email,designation.checked)">Submit</md-button>
</div>
```

Controller function

```
  this.submitUser = function (email, designation) {
 console.log(email, designation)

  }
```

Comment: checkboxes are mutually exclusive -> consider using radio buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you are implementing checkbox
Use ng-checked instead of ng-model

```
<div ng-repeat="designation in $manageController.designations">
 <md-checkbox ng-checked="designation.checked" ng-change="$manageController.change(designation)">

{{ designation.name }}
   </md-checkbox>
```